# Rank of a matrix whose all entries have the form $m^k$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

The original problem is:

> Compute the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}
>  1^k & 2^k & 3^k  & \cdots  & n^k  \\ 
>  2^k& 3^k  & 4^k  &\cdots  & (n+1)^k \\ 
>  3^k& 4^k & 5^k  &\cdots  & (n+2)^k \\ 
>  \vdots&\vdots  &\vdots  &\ddots   & \vdots\\ 
>  n^k& (n+1)^k  & (n+2)^k  &\cdots  &(2n-1)^k 
> \end{vmatrix}$$ where $n\ge 2$ and $0\le k\le n-2.$

The answer is $0$, but I want to find the rank of the above matrix. While solving the original one, I found a beautiful identity. That is, for all $x$: $$\displaystyle \sum _{l=0}^{k+1} {{k+1}\choose l}\cdot (-1)^l\cdot (x+l)^k=0$$

I have two questions:

1. Base on the above identity, is the rank of the matrix equal to $k+1$?
2. Is there a name for the above identity?